# How to itearate foreach loop in smarty as key maps to val in php

Tags: foreach, key, smarty, associative-array

I am trying to use foreach loop in smarty after assigning an associative array with unordered keys but it is not working. I need both the keys and the values. How do I do this.

The assigned array :

```
$arr[34] = 'Profile';
$arr[70] = 'Logo';
$arr[300] = 'Items';

$this->assign('arr', $arr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`foreach`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl).

Example, adjusted to your array:

```
<ul>
{foreach $arr as $keyvar=>$itemvar}
    <li>Key {$keyvar} : {$itemvar} </li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

The [Smarty manual](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) has some more examples to help you further if needed.